# Can I run Ubuntu on intel atom using virtualbox?

Tags: virtualbox

Is it possible to run any Ubuntu version on the intel atom? If so, how? What image to use? I wish to run on chuwl hi8 tablet. I have not tried virtualbox on chuwi hi8.

Answer (score 0):

If you have good amount of memory, you probably could run it. However, it would run on a very slow performance.

Answer (score 0):

I actually ran kali linux and puppy linux thru virtualbox (all three should be capitalized) last night simultaneously!